# What is VerticalPanningRoot (C# Metro ScrollBar Template)

Tags: c#, scrollbar, microsoft-metro, controltemplate

I am currently looking at the C# Metro default controltemplate for scrollbar. And in it the scrollbar template, there is this portion that called verticalpanningroot. Do you have any idea which part of the scrollbar UI is it responsible to render?

```
<Grid x:Name="VerticalPanningRoot" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="66">
    <Border x:Name="VerticalPanningThumb" 
            Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarPanningBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ScrollBarPanningBorderThemeBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{StaticResource ScrollBarPanningBorderThemeThickness}" 
           Width="4" MinHeight="17"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `x:Name="VerticalPanningRoot"`, it just means that you can access your `Grid` by it's name in your code behind (C#) which is `VerticalPanningRoot`.

Example:

```
VerticalPanningRoot.HorizontalAlignement = // something
```

**Edit:**

Your `Grid` is actually holding the "thumb" (the `Border` element) of the `ScrollBar` (the thumb is the part you can drag and drop to go down and up more faster).

You can see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Blogs/37366/scroll.png) all the `ScrollBar` parts, this image is taken from this [tuto](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF).

Comment: Hi, I meant which part of the scrollbar UI is it rendering